# Find the last record of group of overlapped records

Tags: mysql, innodb, select, group-by

I have a little dilemma with filtering out result. 
The result and what I want to achieve is not very trivial and I didn't find an answer anywhere after extensive search.  So here is my problem:

I have a table: `Query` with columns 
`startIndex` and `endIndex` (of type Int(20)) defining range

Here is example subset of our table

`` CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `query` (
`id` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `indexStart` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `indexEnd` int(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci; ``

`` INSERT INTO `query` (`id`, `indexStart`, `indexEnd`) VALUES
(1, 1, 5),
(2, 4, 7),
(3, 7, 9),
(4, 12, 15),
(5, 15, 16),
(6, 16, 17); ``

`+----+------------+----------+
| id | indexStart | indexEnd |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 |          1 |        5 |
|  2 |          4 |        7 |
|  3 |          7 |        9 |
|  4 |         12 |       15 |
|  5 |         15 |       16 |
|  6 |         16 |       17 |
+----+------------+----------+`

The output of query  should be

`+----+------------+----------+--+
| id | indexStart | indexEnd |  |
+----+------------+----------+--+
|  3 |          7 |        9 |  |
|  6 |         17 |       17 |  |
+----+------------+----------+--+`

I want to find the min max solution - 
the last record of the first overlapping group.

Overlapping group should be defined by records that are  `indexEnd` >=  `indexStart` of another record in the group

In the example subset, I should get the record with id `3` when I execute the desired SQL query,

Because the previous records for a group are overlapping indexStart and indexEnd, and the record with index 4 have `indexStart` 12 which is greater than the previous record's `indexEnd` 9 so a gap between records is formed, so the record with id 3 is the last record of first overlapping group.

Comment: If you edit your question to include some code to show what you have tried and what the answer should look like, it would make it easier to respond.

Comment: I absolutely have no idea how to approach to this problem I had idea to select distinct 

`select distinct *
from (
   select
     min(least(table1, indexStart)),
     max(greatest(table2, indexEnd))
` or something like that but I don't know